# UNcrop (whitespace fill) a pdf

Tags: pdf

Suppose I have a pdf that is not an 8.5 by 11 aspect ratio. I want to convert this to 8.5 by 11 by filling in whitespace whereever it is necessary.

Is there a tool that will do this?